# getting an empty array from a request to eventful api

Tags: python, api

Im trying to use the eventful api to get information about only music events (concerts) between two dates. For example I want to get the below information about each concert from 20171012 to 20171013:

```
- city
- performer
- country
- latitude
- longitude
- genre
- title
- image
- StarTime
```

Im using a python example available online and change it to get the data above. But for now its not working Im just able to get this information:

```
 {'latitude': '40.4', 
  'longitude': '-3.68333', 
  'start_time': '2017-10-12 20:00:00', 
  'city_name': 'Madrid', 'title': 'Kim Waters & Maysa Smooth en Hot Jazz Festival'}
```

But the  performer, genre country and image url its not working. Do you know how to get that information? When I change the python example below to get this information it returns always a empty array.

python example working: (However, without getting the performer, genre, country and image url, if I add theese elements to the event_features I get an empty array)

```
   import requests
   import datetime

def get_event(user_key, event_location , start_date, end_date, event_features, fname):

    data_lst = []  # output
    start_year = int(start_date[0:4])
    start_month = int(start_date[4:6])
    start_day = int(start_date[6:])

    end_year = int(end_date[0:4])
    end_month = int(end_date[4:6])
    end_day = int(end_date[6:])

    start_date = datetime.date(start_year, start_month, start_day)
    end_date = datetime.date(end_year, end_month, end_day)
    step = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    while start_date <= end_date:

        date = str(start_date.year)
        if start_date.month < 10:
            date += '0' + str(start_date.month)
        else:
            date += str(start_date.month)

        if start_date.day < 10:
            date += '0' + str(start_date.day)
        else:
            date += str(start_date.day)
        date += "00"
        date += "-" + date

        url = "http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?"
        url += "&app_key=" + user_key
        url += "&location=" + event_location
        url += "&date=" + date
        url += "&page_size=250"
        url += "&sort_order=popularity"
        url += "&sort_direction=descending"
        url += "&q=music"
        url+= "&c=music"

        data = requests.get(url).json()

        try:
            for i in range(len(data["events"]["event"])):
                data_dict = {}
                for feature in event_features:
                    data_dict[feature] = data["events"]["event"][i][feature]
                data_lst.append(data_dict)
        except:
            pass

        print(data_lst)
        start_date += step


def main():

    user_key = ""
    event_location = "Madrid"
    start_date = "20171012"
    end_date = "20171013"
    event_location = event_location.replace("-", " ")
    start_date = start_date
    end_date = end_date
    event_features = ["latitude", "longitude", "start_time"]
    event_features += ["city_name", "title"]
    event_fname = "events.csv"

    get_event(user_key, event_location, start_date, end_date, event_features, event_fname)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your `event_features` list only includes those five elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just put with that 5 elements because like that its working. If I add performer for example it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the data returned by eventful.com, a few things are clear:

1. For country, the field to be used is country_name. This was missing from your "event_features" list
2. There can be multiple performers for each event. To get all the performers, you need to add "performers" to your "event_features" list
3. There is no field named Genre and hence you cannot find Genre
4. The "image" field is always None. This means there is no image available.

Here is modified code. Hopefully it works much better and it will help you move forward.

```
import datetime
import requests

data_lst = []  # output
event_features = ["latitude", "longitude", "start_time", "city_name",
                  "country_name", "title", "image", "performers"]

def get_event(user_key, event_location, start_date, end_date):

    start_year = int(start_date[0:4])
    start_month = int(start_date[4:6])
    start_day = int(start_date[6:])

    end_year = int(end_date[0:4])
    end_month = int(end_date[4:6])
    end_day = int(end_date[6:])

    start_date = datetime.date(start_year, start_month, start_day)
    end_date = datetime.date(end_year, end_month, end_day)
    step = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    while start_date <= end_date:

        date = str(start_date.year)
        if start_date.month < 10:
            date += '0' + str(start_date.month)
        else:
            date += str(start_date.month)

        if start_date.day < 10:
            date += '0' + str(start_date.day)
        else:
            date += str(start_date.day)
        date += "00"
        date += "-" + date

        url = "http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?"
        url += "&app_key=" + user_key
        url += "&location=" + event_location
        url += "&date=" + date
        url += "&page_size=250"
        url += "&sort_order=popularity"
        url += "&sort_direction=descending"
        url += "&q=music"
        url += "&c=music"

        data = requests.get(url).json()
        print "==== Data Returned by eventful.com ====\n", data

        try:
            for i in range(len(data["events"]["event"])):
                data_dict = {}
                for feature in event_features:
                    data_dict[feature] = data["events"]["event"][i][feature]
                data_lst.append(data_dict)
        except IndexError:
            pass

        print "===================================="
        print data_lst
        start_date += step


def main():

    user_key = "Enter Your Key Here"
    event_location = "Madrid"
    start_date = "20171012"
    end_date = "20171013"
    event_location = event_location.replace("-", " ")
    start_date = start_date
    end_date = end_date
    #event_fname = "events.csv"

    get_event(user_key, event_location, start_date, end_date)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should debug your problem and **not to ignore all exceptions**.

Replace lines `try: ... except: pass` by:

```
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    if "event" in data.get("event", {}):
        for row in data["events"]["event"]:
           # print(row)  # you can look here what are the available data, while debugging
           data_dict = {feature: row[feature] for feature in features}
           data_lst.append(data_dict)
    else:
        pass  # a problem - you can do something here
```

You will see a `KeyError` with a name of the missing `feature` that is not present in "row". You should fix missing features and **read documentation about API** of that service. Country feature is probably "country_name" similarly to "city_name". Maybe you should set the "include" parameter to specify more sections of details in search than defaults only.

---

An universal `try: ... except: pass` should never used, because "Errors should never pass silently." ([The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/))

Read **[Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)**:

> ... The last except clause may omit the exception name(s), to serve as a wildcard. Use this with extreme caution, since it is easy to mask a real programming error in this way! ...

A more important command where unexpected exceptions are possible is `requests.get(url).json()`, e.g. TimeoutException. Anyway you should not continue the "while" loop if there is a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.But in the documentation appears country so shoulded work.

Comment: Use `row.get(feature)` to get `None` when some feature is missing instead of an error.

Comment: @Javier I agree that it is better for production, but at the beginning of development when even the upstream API is not implemented enough it is better to fix a typo in column names and to think which columns can be sometimes missing, in order to not have finally an unnoticed string "None" somewhere besides empty string.

Comment: If the data has optional fields, it's inescapable. In production I would not make the code more permissive as it would complicate finding new problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully pull data from the Eventful API for the `performer`, `image`, and `country` fields.  However, I don't think the Eventful Search API supports `genre` - I don't see it [in their documentation](http://api.eventful.com/docs/events/search).

To get `country`, I added `"country_name", "country_abbr"` to your event_features array.  That adds these values to the resulting JSON:

```
'country_abbr': u'ESP',
'country_name': u'Spain'
```

`Performer` also can be retrieved by adding `"performers"` to `event_features`.  That will add this to the JSON output:

```
'performers': {
    u'performer': {
        u'name': u'Kim Waters', 
        u'creator': u'evdb', 
        u'url': u'http://concerts.eventful.com/Kim-Waters?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic', 
        u'linker': u'evdb', 
        u'short_bio': u'Easy Listening / Electronic / Jazz', u'id': u'P0-001-000333271-4'
    }
}
```

To retrieve images, add `image` to the `event_features` array.  Note that not all events have images, however. You will either see `'image': None` or

```
'image': {
    u'medium': {
        u'url': u'http://d1marr3m5x4iac.cloudfront.net/store/skin/no_image/categories/128x128/other.jpg', 
        u'width': u'128', 
        u'height': u'128'
    }, 
    u'thumb': {
        u'url': u'http://d1marr3m5x4iac.cloudfront.net/store/skin/no_image/categories/48x48/other.jpg', 
        u'width': u'48', 
        u'height': u'48'
    }
}
```

Good luck!  :)